# Kendodropdown value to textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have kendodropdown, I want to populate the selected value from kendodropdown to a textbox  ater clicking a edit button. I use mvc.razor. please help.
 controller1/view1

```
     @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("labeldropdown")
      .DataTextField("Tasks")
        .DataValueField("ID")
          .OptionLabel("Select label")
         .AutoBind(true)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 72px;font-size:12px; " })
        .DataSource(source =>
   {   source.Read(read =>
          {
          read.Action("BindStates", "Resource");
       });
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
      )

<input type="button" value="New" class="k-button" id="newLabel" />
  <input type="button" value="Edit" class="k-button" id="editLabel" />
```

controller1/view2

```
 <input type="button" value="OK" class="k-button" id="labelok" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="k-button" id="labelcancel" />
  @Html.TextBox("labeltxt", null, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
```

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far. Asking for solutions here is going to count against you. Lets see what you have done.

Comment: Thankyou for the response.now I attached the code.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("labeldropdown")
      .DataTextField("Tasks")
        .DataValueField("ID")
          .OptionLabel("Select label")
         .AutoBind(true)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 72px;font-size:12px; " })
        .DataSource(source =>
   {   source.Read(read =>
          {
          read.Action("BindStates", "Resource");
       });
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
      )


     @Html.TextBox("labeltxt", null, new {id = "txtText", @class = "k-textbox" })

    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="k-button" id="editLabel" />

        $("#editLabel").click(function () {

              $("#txtText").val($("#labeldropdown").data("kendoComboBox").value());
              $("#CoutryID").data("kendoComboBox").value();//This is for ID               
              $("#CoutryID").data("kendoComboBox").text();  //This is for text             
        });
```

So you have to set value on based on above code.